# Order one table based on column of another table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to order `myTable1` based on a `column` in `myTable2`. I have tried this using all kinds of `joins`, for example `right`,`left`,`inner` and just `join` on it's own. The two following SQL queries have got me the closest the the end goal but they still aren't right.
The following query correctly selects all the correct records but does not display them in the desired order. They are simply being output on the order they are stored within `myTable1`

`SELECT myTable1.* FROM myTable1 INNER JOIN myTable2 b ON myTable1.myRef = b.myRef WHERE col2 = 1 ORDER BY b.col3 ASC`

The following query correctly orders the records according to `col2` within `myTable2` but for some reason it only returns some of the results, not all of them.

`SELECT myTable1.* FROM myTable1 LEFT JOIN myTable2 b ON myTable1.myRef = b.myRef WHERE col2 = 1 ORDER BY b.col3 ASC`

For the record i'm using `mysqli`

Comment: Are you trying to order by col2 or by col3?

Comment: Rather than just `select myTable1.*` go ahead and use the first select, but `select *`. Take careful note of col3 - you will notice that it is in ascending order by col3, and any ordering by the order they are stored in myTable1 is just by chance.

Comment: @PeterBowers sorry i think i made a typo. I would like it ordered by `col3` of `myTable2`

Comment: So did you try the `select *` with your first query that I suggested? I really think you're going to find that your first query is really correct already.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT myTable1.* FROM myTable1 JOIN (SELECT myTable2.* FROM myTable2) b ON myTable1.myRef = b.myRef WHERE col2 = 1 ORDER BY b.col3 ASC
```

> If your *WHERE* statement is referecing *col2* correctly, this
>   approach should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks, i just tried this and unfortunately it had the same result as an `inner join`. Only some of the records are selected.